# how to log out with adaj.js in teams tab

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-teams

Our application is integrated with Azure-active-directory by adal.js. It works well except for logout

the logout function just like this

```html
const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config)
...
authContext.logOut()
```

it will bring you to microsoft website to finish the logout and redirect back. whatever, it works well in chrome, but not for teams static tab. It looks like the redirecion cannot be made in teams tab.

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the logout endpoint url in your azure auth settings? When the logout method is called, the library clears the application cache in the browser storage and sends a logout request to the Azure AD instance's logout endpoint.

authContext.logOut(); The default behavior is to redirect the user to window.location.href after logout. If a postLogoutRedirectUri value is set at the config time, the user will be redirected to that URI.

Comment: I have set the logout endpoint url, and it works well if you access it directly. I guess the problem is that the teams don't allow the url redirection.

Comment: Where you have set the endpoint url? It should be set where your bot is registered in azure portal. Please provide some more information on setting endpoint url.